# Bind Data after TCP receive

Tags: c#, data-binding, compact-framework, tcp

I have this strange problem all day now. I dunno if you handled something similar.
I used two different serializers and now i know its not this problem.

Im sending some data over TCP Sockets. Serialize -> Send -> Deserialize,
everything works ok, i can get my objects search through them, use they're properties!
But, if e.g receive a `BusinessObject[]` and convert into `List<BusinessObject>`, then bind
the list in a `Control.DataSource = businessObjectList;` BOOM! `NotSupportedException`.

Tried it
with 3 different controls. Same behaviour. My head is empty of ideas right now!!
The Send TCP happens on Desktop Framework, Receive on Compact Framework. But i dont think
this has to do with anything.

I wish for an explanation on this!

Comment: Is there any more detail in the exception? a string message? And does the same data-binding approach work in regular / winforms?

Comment: Bro i think i found, soon as you sai about regular winfors, i created one and bind in a DataGridView, and then i got the details, i didnt get in the Compact Framework and i supposed i installed the information pack (dont remember the name),its a Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'grid' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on. I guess this is the error, i will try to fix. Any ideas about handling cross-thread and bind in controls? i know a solution with delegate, but im open on suggestions and latest solutions!

Answer (score 0):

Re cross-thread error... simply don't try binding from the wrong thread! You'll have to switch back to the main thread for UI updates, sorry. As it happens I *have* used a cross-thread safe list in the past (for whatever meaning "safe" has when multiple threads are mutating the same list... it raises notification events on the UI thread, I mean) - but it *certainly* won't work on CF.

Comment: Thanx anyway Marc :) I think i will stay with Control.InvokeRequired, would be great to handle the data before i pass them out of the Data Library, but i saw too the effect of not working the solution i found!